# Kohana ORM Relationships

Tags: kohana, kohana-orm

I have a couple of tables and have defined relationships for them.

```
{Table Department} {Table Unit} {Table Branch}
```

A Department can have more than one branch, a branch can only belong to one department. I need to be able to get the department name, departmentid, branchname

```
Branch has an instance of departmentid in it.
```

How do I pull this in one ORM call?

```
class Model_Admin_Departments extends ORM
```

{

```
protected $_has_many = array('branches' => array ());


class Model_Admin_Branches extends ORM
```

{
    protected $_belongs_to = array('departments ' => array());

I have also created the foreign key constraints on the db side with action cascade on delete. Could this cause problems or that is fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the right [relationships declared](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/orm/relationships) you should be able to use the [`with(...)` method](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/ORM#with) on your ORM object.

Comment: I am getting Undefined index: division_id. Look at my code sample in the new edit.

Comment: I got the problem. I needed to declare the foreign key in the relationship declaration to make it work. The default was looking for 'declarationname_id'  This link saved me a lot:  http://kohanaframework.blogspot.com/2010/12/kohana-3-orm-relationships.html